# multistage azure devops pipeline - skip stage sequentially

Tags: azure-devops, azure-pipelines, azure-pipelines-yaml

I have an azure devops pipeline which run as follow:

```
parameters:
- name: environments
  type: object
  default:
  - a
  - b


stages:
- ${{ each env in parameters.environments }}:
  - stage: Plan_${{ env }}
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
    jobs:
    - job: Plan
      steps:
      - template: s1.yml
        parameters:
          env: ${{ env }}
          action: plan
          workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}'
  
  - stage: Apply_${{ env }}
    dependsOn: Plan_${{ env }}
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.outputs['Plan.x.y'], 'true'))   #where x is a task from template s1.yml and y is the output variable;
    jobs: 
     .................
```

Running this pipeline, it runs sequential not as I wish, I need. I need to have something like:

- if for the a environment, if Plan_a matches the condition to skip the apply_a stage for dev but to continue with rest pipeline jobs like Plan_b where is checking again for y outputvariable if there are changes or not and depending on this to run the apply_b stage and so on...in case I will add more environments.

Currently, it is working as: considering no changes for both environment, pipeline starts with plan.a, it matches the condition then it skips apply.a, skips plan.b and apply.b .

I tried in parallel mode, introducing before Plan a new stage and to make Plan to depends by that stage and they working in parallel, but in sequent mode, how to make it works as I need?

ps: I tried excluding dependsOn, not working;
I tried with parallel depending on another previous stage if I create it but I need it  in sequential mode.

```
I tried this way:




stages:
        - ${{ each env in parameters.environments }}:
          - stage: Plan_${{ env }}
            condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'PullRequest'))
            jobs:
            - job: Plan
              steps:
              - template: s1.yml
                parameters:
                  env: ${{ env }}
                  action: plan
                  workingDirectory: '${{ parameters.workingDirectory }}'
       **- ${{ each env in parameters.environments }}:**
          - stage: Apply_${{ env }}
            dependsOn: Plan_${{ env }}
            condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.outputs['Plan.x.y'], 'true'))   #where x is a task from template s1.yml and y is the output variable;
            jobs: 
             .................
```

and the pipeline now is working in this way: starts with plan.a (finishing it, result no changes), continue with plan.b (result no changes) then skipping apply.a , skipping apply.b .

I need them to be sequentially plan.a, apply.a; plan.b, apply.b and skipping the apply after each plan stage started and having an output variable that match or not condition.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

## Solution 1

Add `dependsOn: []` on in the `Plan_${{ env }}` stage:

```
parameters:
- name: environments
  type: object
  default:
  - a
  - b

stages:
- ${{ each env in parameters.environments }}:
  - stage: Plan_${{ env }}
    condition: and(succeeded(), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'))
    dependsOn: []
    jobs:
    - job: Plan
      steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        name: SetVariable
        inputs:
          targetType: "inline"
          script: |
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runApply;isOutput=true]false"
  
  - stage: Apply_${{ env }}
    dependsOn: Plan_${{ env }}
    condition: and(succeeded(), eq(dependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.outputs['Plan.SetVariable.runApply'], 'true'))
    jobs:
    - job: Apply
      steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        name: SetVariable
        inputs:
          targetType: "inline"
          script: |
            Write-Host "Running Apply"
```

Output:

[image]

## Solution 2

The reason Plan_B is being blocked is because the stage before it is in a skipped state, which is not succeeded. To get around this we can alter the condition from `succeeded()` to `not(or(failed(), canceled()))`.

```
parameters:
- name: environments
  type: object
  default:
  - a
  - b

stages:
- ${{ each env in parameters.environments }}:
  - stage: Plan_${{ env }}
    condition: and(not(or(failed(), canceled())), ne(variables['Build.Reason'], 'Manual'))
    jobs:
    - job: Plan
      steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        name: SetVariable
        inputs:
          targetType: "inline"
          script: |
            Write-Host "##vso[task.setvariable variable=runApply;isOutput=true]false"
  
  - stage: Apply_${{ env }}
    dependsOn: Plan_${{ env }}
    condition: and(not(or(failed(), canceled())), eq(dependencies.Plan_${{ env }}.outputs['Plan.SetVariable.runApply'], 'true'))
    jobs:
    - job: Apply
      steps:
      - task: PowerShell@2
        name: SetVariable
        inputs:
          targetType: "inline"
          script: |
            Write-Host "Running Apply"
```

Output:

[image]

Comment: Running this way is like:
plan.a -> apply.a
plan.b -> apply.b 

I need to havem them in same way: plan.a -> apply.a -> plan.b -> apply.b  (even if apply.a is skipped, plan.b to start and not to be skipped).

Comment: Thank you for the clarification @be9inn3r , I have edited my answer to provide the alternative solution. I hope this can help you.

Comment: You're right, adding not(or(failed(), canceled())) in the plan stage makes the entire pipeline work as I need. 

I found this too and tested it before to see your comment, but thanks for confirmation and thanks for your time. you helped me these days :)

Comment: Nice job finding the solution. Feel free to mark this as the accepted answer if it did indeed solve the problem though :- )

Comment: Sorry, I am back.

Tested again and the problem is that Apply_b to work and not to be skipped is to have also for the Apply_${{env}} in the condition: not(or(failed(), canceled())) , right? 
Because without it, the Apply _b is skipped directly even if in Plan_b are changes detected.

Comment: You're right. Using succeeded() on the apply_env stage causes it to be skipped if any previous stages had been skipped. Like you have mentioned, using not(or(failed(), canceled())) will instead of succeeded() will give us the expected behaviour. I have updated my answer to reflect this.